# Is it possible to make a TreeMap from a Map literal?

Tags: dart

I have a Map literal, an I want it to be a TreeMap, but by default I believe it's a LinkedHashMap. Casting a LinkedHashMap to a TreeMap won't work as it's not a subtype.

Basically, I'm looking for the simplest way to make this work:

```
var map = <int, int>{for(int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) intervals[i][0] : i} as SplayTreeMap;
```

As mentioned before, casting as SplayTreeMap won't work as they types don't align.

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SplayTreeMap.from` constructor to create a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html). There isn't any way to cast it as you said.

Remove the `as` from your current code and add this to get your `SplayTreeMap`:

```dart
var newMap = SplayTreeMap.from(map);
```

Depending on your key type and your use case, you can pass `compare` and `isValidKey` parameters as well. Full constructor definition:

```dart
SplayTreeMap<K, V>.from(
  Map other,
  [int compare(
    K key1,
    K key2
  ),
  bool isValidKey(
    dynamic potentialKey
  )]
)
```